# When migrating, moderators should be notified if a post with an identical title exists on the target site

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderators

[Migrations are rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225679/270345) if exact duplicates already exist on the target site. Shog9 says that moderators can override this. The implication is that they need to take some extra action to override it, but the actual behaviour seems to be that the check is simply bypassed for moderators. [Gilles noted this back then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97632/check-to-make-sure-a-duplicate-does-not-exist-before-migrating#comment737830_225679), and the response was that mods should coordinate with mods on the target site.

Recently, a mod migrated a question from meta to main that OP had posted to both (possibly accidentally). (That's to say, the migrating mod was a mod on the target site.) At the time of the migration, the titles were identical, but one of the bodies had been edited. I VTC'd the migrated post as a dupe, the mod saw that later, and closed and deleted it, as they would have done in the first place had they known. Of course, the mod thinks that they should have checked OP's posting history, but IMHO with *identical titles* some indication should have been given to them.